# Forward declared functions and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I've encountered an interesting pattern in the [unconstexpr](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr-cpp20) library.

According to the readme, the idea is that given a forward declared auto return type function, the return type can't be deduced before the function is actually defined, and this allows some SFINAE magic.

I thought this language feature could be useful for a few other ideas, and did some experiments with it, and it looks like gcc and clang behaves differently when the function isn't a template: gcc works the same, while clang reports an error.

And based on what the error message of clang shows, maybe it shouldn't work even for a template?

So the questions are:

- is the template part (allowed by both clang and gcc) allowed by the standard?
- which compiler is correct about the non template version?

Simplified code (also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ymLcwc)):

```
struct S {};

constexpr auto f1();

template <typename T>
constexpr auto f2(T);

// compilation error with clang:
// function with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
template <typename T, typename = decltype(f1())>
void test1_1() {}
template <typename T>
void test1_1() {}

// compiles with clang, even if f2 will never be defined
template <typename T, typename = decltype(f2<T>(T{}))>
constexpr int test1_2(int) { return 1; }
template <typename T>
constexpr int test1_2(float) { return 2; }

/////////////////

int g1_2() {
  return test1_2<S>(0);
}

constexpr auto f1() { return 1; }

// comment-uncomment this:
// the value returned by g2_@ will change
// /*
template <typename T>
constexpr auto f2(T) {
  return 2;
}
// */

// can be defined here
template <typename T, typename = decltype(f1())>
void test2_1() {}

int g2_2() {
  return test1_2<S>(0);
}
```

Note: originally I also mentioned that it behaves differently with friends, and that it seems to be working without an auto return type - those were user errors on my part.

Comment: `// SFINAE works: substitution failure ??
  // test1_6<4>();` That compile for me by fixing typo `4` -> `S`...

Comment: Uh, that's right, looks like I missed that when changing the parameter to a type. That solves the second difference then, but the first is still there.

Comment: Another thing with friend functions, is that they can only be found by ADL (if not also declared in regular scope). so passing parameter `wrap` might also solve some issues.

Comment: I fixed the typo you found (also edited the example code), and now there's no difference between friends and normal functions. The remaining question is, why does it work with auto, and why it doesn't work without a template? (or: should the part that works work?)

Comment: It's not that `f2` is a template: `decltype(f2<int>(0))` wouldn't compile. It's that the expression `f2<T>(T{})` depends on type `T`, and so instantiation of `f2<T>` is delayed until `test1_2` itself is instantiated and `T` becomes known. At that point, the definition of `f2` is already available.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but with some modifications, it compiles even if f2 is never defined: https://godbolt.org/z/EoQafP . And if it is defined, the results will be different for g1_2 and g2_2, so the compiler doesn't wait for the definition for the first.

Comment: I also failed to notice that `test_1_1` is only rejected by clang, not gcc - it works with gcc. But the error message by clang suggest that it also shouldn't work with a template.

Comment: After some standard reading, my guess would be that 9.2.8.5 .6 and also .11 (latest C++20 draft) makes this decltype ill formed: "If the name of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type appears in an expression, the program is
ill-formed" - but I wouldn't say that for sure, so still looking for a definite answer if somebody knows.